# Can`t normally filter data from mongodb tables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Creating somne rest-api on express+mongodb. There is a problem: two models "Product" and "ExampleProduct". There is a field "productId" in the second one, that references to the "Product" model. I need to filter examples from model "Product" by "ExampleProduct", but i can`t do it that simple. I tried to put them in the array like in code below, but it returns array with only one element of all that i am searching.
I know that forEach works kinda strange in things like this, and i tried to use filter() also, but that was unfortunately wrong too.

```
        var arr = [];
                async function Add(){
                    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                    await ExampleProduct.find(async function (err, exampleProduct) {
                        exampleProduct.forEach(async element=>{
                            
                            await Product.findById(element.productId,async function(err, product){
                                
                                arr.unshift(product);
                                resolve(arr);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                  });
                }
```